# How to fine-tune a following SQL query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to replace a nested loop to merge join without force option , I've given table data and query's below thanks.

## Table 1:

```
   N_ID S_NAME  DEPT
    1   NAME1   DEPT1
    2   NAME2   DEPT2
    3   NAME3   DEPT3
```

## Table 2:

```
  N_ID  S_CITY  PHONE
    1   CITY1   PHONE1
    2   CITY2   PHONE2
    3   CITY3   PHONE3
```

I've created index like below :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NC ON TBL1(N_ID)
INCLUDE (S_NAME)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_NC ON TBL2(N_ID)
```

## Query:

```
SELECT A.N_ID,S_NAME FROM TBL1 A
INNER JOIN TBL2 B ON A.N_ID=B.N_ID;
```

Here's my Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to replace Nested Loop with Merge Join? Let SQL Server decide which join operation is best for your data.

Comment: If I've lots of data in tb2 or tb1., then the estimated number of execution, increasing depends upon how much data has tb1 or tb2.

Comment: Make sure indexes are not fragmented, statistics are up-to-date and queries should execute just fine.

Comment: @Thangadurai How much data from the two tables is being returned? It would be really helpful if you could [**paste the plan**](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have reasons of forcing Merge join over Nested loops,i would not recommend doing that..

SQLServer internally implements joins as three operators

1.Nested loops
2.Hash
3.Merge

Each has its own advantages and its not possible to say,one join is better than other..SQL may choose any join based on many factors and  overall,it chooses a plan with less cost...

Coming to your question,As per Docs..

Nested loops is choosen when ..

> If one join input is small (fewer than 10 rows) and the other join input is fairly large and indexed on its join columns, an index nested loops join is the fastest join operation because they require the least I/O and the fewest comparisons

Also MSDN explains cases where nested loop join is effective..

> A nested loops join is particularly effective if the outer input is small and the inner input is preindexed and large. In many small transactions, such as those affecting only a small set of rows, index nested loops joins are superior to both merge joins and hash joins.

So unless you force a hint and engineer data in such a way,SQL chooses merge join..Merge join is not possible in your case

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191426(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: You don't necessarily have to force a hint join. Since the type of operator that is used is determined by the Cardinality Estimator, then re-writing the query in a way that "fakes" a higher row count can make the Optimizer use a more appropriate operator. [Have a look at Adam Machanic's row goals talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O8BGYC8_qEI).